# Move MySQL Data from one Table to Another Skip duplicate (or overwrite)

Tags: php, mysql, move, duplicates

I need to upload csv into mysql. Regularly.

So I am planing to upload csv to a temporary table. Than move data from `temporary_table` to `main_table`.

Now, I need help:

1. How can I move data. And (a) skip duplicate, or (b) overwrite duplicate
2. The csv currently contains 55566 rows, and will increasing day by day. So, how to handle execute time.
3. Best practice to import csv to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

1. > How can I move data.

   Use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html).

   > And (a) skip duplicate, or (b) overwrite duplicate

   Define a [`UNIQUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/constraint-primary-key.html) key constraint on the columns that determine whether records are duplicate or not; then:

   (a) use [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html); or

   (b) use either [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replace.html).
2. > The csv currently contains 55566 rows, and will increasing day by day. So, how to handle execute time.

   Rotate your CSV file after each upload so that past records are not repeatedly uploaded.
3. > Best practice to import csv to mysql.

   Use either *[`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html)* or [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html).

Comment: I would use `mysqlimport` with the `UNIQUE` key.  It can handle CSV directly when configured and has flags for ignore/replace.  You'll probably have to load directly into your main table or your duplicate removal/updating will be very complicated.